# How to get the timezone offset of a place using JavaScript with the Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, timezone-offset

I'm newer to programming and am currently trying to pull the UTC timezone offset value from a Google Autocomplete search.

Currently, I am able to pull the latitude and longitude in JavaScript from the autocomplete selection using this code:

```
var item_Lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
var item_Lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
```

What would work for the timezone offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Timezone api from google for this purpose.
Since you already have the latitude and longitude of the place , you can simply plug these as query parameters along with the timestamp of your current place in the following api request.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=`38.908133`,`-77.047119`&timestamp=`1458000000`&key=`YOUR_API_KEY`

More information can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/start).